# How to check if a PHP project works well with a new PHP Version

Tags: php

Is there a **good** way to test if a PHP project works well with a new version of PHP?
Lets say we have a project developed under PHP 5.0 and want to run it now with PHP 5.4. The project have no unit tests or something like that.

Just run it with PHP 5.4 and click around to see if there are errors is not save enough.

Comment: Sounds like this might do better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: PHP provides a comprehensive list of backward-incompatible changes and deprecated features with every release. Simply run through those lists and check whether you're using any of those features.

Comment: @Wooble as I said in the question, the project have no unit tests.

Comment: @Spudley I hoped for some automated tools to do this work. If there are no tools or checkers then it will be hard to check a BIG project. I found the lists, like: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php
Now I could search all the sourcecodes for this functions and watch each functioncall manuell if there is something bad. That would take quite a while and in my opinion it is not that save to just check everything manuell. My question is, how would a professional PHP Dev do this job.

Comment: A professional dev would have regression tests.

Comment: @Wooble That is not the question here. it is not my project. I want to see how a professional dev have unit tests out of the nowhere in a external project.

Answer (score 6):

1. Run your tests. If you don't have tests, write some now under PHP 5.0. Then run them under 5.4. If they break, then you've found something that needs to be fixed. Having a suite of test scripts is good practice anyway so if you haven't got any, this is a good opportunity to start writing them. Look up [phpUnit](http://phpunit.de/), which is the most common PHP tool for writing unit tests.

   For creating a test suite on an existing project, I recommend using a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/) which can record a browser session. Turn on the recording and start testing as normal. Voila: One repeatable test. You're going to have to do this kind of testing anyway, so you may as well record them. Granted, those are *functional tests*, rather than *unit tests*, but they are tests all the same, and if you can cover enough of your functionality with them then you'll have a fairly comprehensive demonstration that the system is working.
2. Syntax check: Use PHP's command-line `-l` option in a batch job to run a syntax check on all your files. This will prove that everything parses successfully.

   That will eliminate the obvious problems.
3. Use a decent IDE to develop your code in. IDEs like Netbeans will highlight syntax issues and warning for you and underline the relevant code. This makes finding bugs much much easier.

   If you're still developing in Notepad, you're missing out on a whole world of good stuff.
4. If you're using `ereg()` or related functions, they need to change to `preg_match()` etc. You can get away with still using `mysql_query()` for DB access, since that's only deprecated in 5.5, but if you're using it you may as well consider this to be a good time to make that change too.
5. Look up the [Migration Guides](https://www.php.net/migration54) provided by PHP. These give full details of all the code-breaking changes between PHP versions. In particular, pay attention to the deprecated features.

   The most significant version for this was 5.3: A *lot* of old code was broken by the features which were deprected in 5.3. These were features like `magic_quotes` and `register_globals`; they had been considered bad practice for a very long time before that, but it took them until 5.3 to actually deprecate them. If you're using them, this will be the biggest problem you'll have to face.
6. Tools like [PHPMD](http://phpmd.org/) and [PHPCodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer), [PHP Lint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/) may help to analyse your code. They aren't really designed for version compatiblity checking, but may help you find issues.